Expo React Native Error - When using "npx create expo-stack" - expected 1 arguments, got 0
Just after running the npx create expo-stack, when I run the npm run start,it returns: ERROR: Exception in HostFunction: expected 1 arguments, got 0, js engine: hermes
this is what I get from the console
I have tried using npm i --legacy-peer-deps to correct the package mismatch but the error remains. However, the app renders the homescreen if i dismiss the error! I have built two apps and have the same bug.
